# Why is insertion into a sorted array O(n)?

Tags: algorithm

Skiena, in The Algorithm Design Manual, states that insertion into a sorted array is O(n). Yet searching for an item in a sorted array is O(log n), because you can do a binary search.

Couldn't insertion also be O(log n), if I did binary search comparisons to figure out where in the array it should go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding the position is only half the battle. Show me how to place a 2 in its place into [1,3,4,5,6,7] using fewer than five move operations.

Answer (score 4):

You can do O(log n) search on a sorted array but when you insert an item you need to shift data, so shift is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary search to figure out where the element should go.
However, inserting the element means that you have to make space for it. This is done by moving all elements after the new element to the right. That takes O(n) complexity.